# Authentication in AngularJS while using a Cookie Based REST based Backend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest, cookies

I am using AngularJS, NodeJS and an Application server which gives me all my REST based services. The typical architecture is as follows:-
[image]

Now the thing is I make the cookie pass to and Fro to manage the requests and responses. This helps me to maintain the session. But I am skeptic that this is not the correct approach to manage the authentication and authorization of the application.

I would like an advice of how to best maintain the session where my REST based server serves me the cookie(JSESSIONID). Please point out the references as well as let me know if I am doing something wrong.

NOTE: I read the response codes in order to understand whether a user is logged in or not. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

REST Services are supposed to be stateless. A good review of Rest API  (http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html#)

The cookie you pass around is for authentication. It tells your server that this user has been authenticated, and ,for efficiency, this step can be skipped.

Authorization is another topic. It is what the authenticated user can do in the systems. Usually user's roles & rights are stored in a session object for efficiency too. However, there're exceptions.

For example, oAuth (http://oauth.net/) uses Tokens that combine both authentication & authorization. The token "tells" the system who you are, and also what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

The flow that you have shown is pretty much I am and many others are used to doing while working on my webapps, however session or cookie based authentication is not considered to be the best option as long as you are working with REST framework as it is supposed to be stateless.

Moreover cookie based auth doesnt work well with CORS and CSRF and authentication from android and IOS apps. Token based auth is preferred. Please see the following links for more information

https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication
https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

Let me know if this was useful.